# jQuery Simple SkillBar Update the Value and graphic bar on click

Tags: jquery, bar-chart

I'm using jQuery [Simple SkillBar](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Responsive-Skill-Bar-Plugin-jQuery-Simple-SkillBar/)

```
<div id="skill1" class="demo" data-width="65" data-background="#FFC107">JavaScript (65%)</div>
<div id="skill2" class="demo" data-width="90" data-background="#FF5722">HTML5+XML (90%)</div>
<div id="skill3" class="demo" data-width="70" data-background="#2196F3">CSS+CSS3 (70%)</div>
<div id="skill4" class="demo" data-width="50" data-background="#F44336">AngularJS (50%)</div>
<div id="skill5" class="demo" data-width="80" data-background="#3B5998">ReactJS + React Native (80%)</div>
```

```js
$('.demo').simpleSkillbar({});
```

As we can see, the bar will show on body load. Now I have an button called `#btn` to set `#skill1` value on click.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#skill1').attr("data-width", "20");
});
```

However the skillbar is not updating. What I need is when I click the button `#btn` then value to `#skill1` will be updating including with the skillbar.

Comment: You have a `.` at the end of your line of JS which will be causing a syntax error. I'd suggest removing that and checking the console for other errors

Comment: I have removed it and still not working. Checked on console and there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the bar like you did, you must specify width through `simpleSkillbar` plugin object.

This will do the job

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#skill1').simpleSkillbar({
  width: 20
  });
});
```

See the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/9mzLvquw/2/